# list multiple in one row in one column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, yajra-datatable

I am sorry but I don't even know how to title this question since I have no clue what to look for.

Here is my problem: I have the following list:

| name | word | hit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | performance | 2 |
| Anna | performance | 5 |
| John | performance | 3 |
| Bill | java | 0 |
| Anna | java | 1 |
| John | java | 3 |
| Bill | test | 4 |
| Anna | test | 5 |
| John | test | 1 |

What I am trying to get is the following:

| name | sum(hit) | words_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | 6 | performance = 2 java = 0, test = 4 |
| Anna | 11 | performance = 5 java = 1, test = 5 |
| John | 7 | performance = 3 java = 3, test = 1 |

I could sum all hits and group by words and so but I only need one dataset each name.

I think I need a subquery or so. How can I get the `words_count` column in that way?

Actually I need it a Laravel controller to display it in a datatable but an SQl statement would help me a lot also.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: It would help if you could share some code, like a model and/or controller method. Because there are more ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: As far as a query goes, `SELECT * FROM my_list` will suffice. Everything else can be resolved in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider, you have a model named `UserPerformance`

```php
$userPerformance = UserPerformance::all();
$result = $userPerformance->groupBy('name');
```

And in your blade template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>sum(hit)</th>
            <th>words_count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($userPerformance as $name => $performance)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $performance->sum('hit') }}</td>
                <td>
                    {{ $performance->map(function($p) { return $p->word.' = '.$p->hit; })->implode(', ') }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also add your `map()` code to your model using an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to keep the blade template clean:

```
class UserPerformance extends Model
{
    public function getWordCountAttribute()
    {
        return $performance->map(function($p) {
            return $p->word.' = '.$p->hit;
        })->implode(', ');
    }
}
```

You can access it like this: `$userPerformanceModel->word_count;`

That also enables you, to re-use the code.  You can also [append](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) this accessor during serialization to use it client-side.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i thank you a lot for your answers.
I could manage it in SQL. So the statement is the following:

```
SELECT name, sum(hit) as points,
GROUP_CONCAT(concat(word, '->'), concat(hit, ' ') separator ' ' ) as words
FROM results
GROUP BY name;
```

This gives me exactly what i need.
I am display my data in a datatable (yajra). I will now "translate" this code to "laravel / php" code to feed my datatable.

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention, that you needed that for yajra datatable. Fyi: I added this as a tag to your question.

Comment: If you need any help translating it, don't hesitate to ask for it :)

Comment: Thanks for your offer :) I got it and its working. I have more columns in my real project. So here is the code: `$data = DB::table('results')->select('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',DB::raw('SUM(hit) as points'),DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(concat(word, '->'), concat(hit, ' ') separator ' ' ) as word"))
            ->having('points','>', 2)
            ->groupBy('email')
            ->orderBy('points')
            ->get();`

Comment: `CONCAT()` can take any number of arguments, so simplify to `CONCAT(word, '->', hit)`

Comment: FWIW, I think this is the wrong approach.